# synonyms for "dislike"

Tags: vocabulary

Suppose someone else was trying to fool me and I found it. So I said "shame on you" to him.

What he did makes me dislike/hate him. So, I would say

> I disrespect him as he was trying to fool me.

Is the sentence clear and natural?

Could "dishonor", "disgrace", "disapprove of" be used for this situation?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with *dislike* itself? Why do you have to find an alternative?

Comment: Thank you, "dislike" is fine. I'd just like to practice my vocabulary.

Comment: When you say _trying to fool me_, do you mean _play a trick on me_ or are you talking about a serious, criminal fraud? Words like _hate, dishonour, disgrace_ are rather strong for someone who has just tricked you as a joke.

Comment: dislike is to not like and there is no synonym for it.

Comment: Consulting a dictionary should be your first step. Not having respect for someone is different to disliking them, and dishonor has a different meaning too.

Answer (score 0):

The following sentence is unnatural and would not be used by someone fluent in English:

> I disrespect him as he was trying to fool me.

Some alternatives are shown below:

- "I dislike him because he is dishonest."
- "I do not like him because he lied to me once."
- "I have no respect for him. There was a past incident in which he lied to me."

Replace the word "as" with "because":

> - "we did not go out ***as*** it was raining outside."
> - "we did not go out ***because*** it was raining outside" (good)

Comment: That first sentence is fine in English.